# How to get user photo using LightOpenID php class for google and yahoo

Tags: lightopenid

I am using LightOpenID php class ie openid.php class. I want to fetch the user photo. But it does not return information about user's photo. Please help me I have to fetch user account photo.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID providers don't have to return any information you've requested.

Here's the list of attributes Google will return if you ask for them:

- country
- email
- first name
- language
- last name

You can find it at [google's openid endpoint documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID).

Google won't return any other attributes, regardless of whether you ask for them or not. Since the user photo isn't on the list, you can't get it.

As for yahoo, [a post on developer.yahoo.com](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2009/12/yahoo_openid_now_with_attribute_exchange/) says that if you request `media/image/default` it will return the profile picture. I don't know whether that information is up to date though. If you still can't get the profile picture by requesting that, then most likely yahoo doesn't support it anymore (or you don't have a profile picture).

Comment: What about Google's OAuth+OpenID hybrid access? Aren't they allowing tat?

Comment: Can you integrate that into LightOpenID?